# For Next loop - Receiving error

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have tried the following simple for next loop in R programming:

```
for(i in 1:100)  { if(i <= 20)  {  next  } print(i) }
```

Below is the error message I am receiving:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "for(i in 1:100) { if(i <= 20) {next} print"
```

Please help me understand why I am receiving the error.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: it is in r programming

Comment: It it whitspace-dependent, where you need new lines between brackets?

Comment: I don't think so. Tried executing some small functions all in 1 line and they were fine

Comment: @ChakK View my answer below. Please accept it if it is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
for (i in 1:100) { 
  if (i<=20) {
    next
  };
  print(i)
}
```

Looks like you missed your semi-colon. You need this to denote the end of a statement.

Comment: There is no need for the `;`. If they copy the code from their question **including linebreaks** into an R console, it works just fine.

Comment: Ah, I see. Someone else edited the code. I've reverted the edit. However, you should include a solution using linebreaks in your answer. In conjunction with code indention they are better practice.

Answer (score 0):

you need to break the line (enter) after {next} and have print(i)} in another line. :) Good Luck